# Using VMWare Fusion for local web dev, how to view local sites in the VM from the Mac

Tags: networking, localhost, vmware, virtual-machine

I'm using VMWare to build a .asp / NET site in a virtual machine running Windows 7 on my Mac, but I'd like to view this from the OSX side, or from other machines on the local network.

On the virtual machine the localhost site publishes to localhost:37886
On the Mac, I've tried to view the VM IP followed by :37886 but to no avail.
Wondered if there's a particular setup required.

Comment: What network adaptors do you have setup? Do you a host only or bridged  one setup? A NAT one won't allow you to access the machine via it's ip.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to access it by accessing your virtual machine ip address from your OSX side through your OSX side broswer. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it won't connect. Wondered if there's anything in-between that I need to do.

Comment: Sadly not, just that the browser cannot establish a connection.